# Stretch one or two divs to whole td with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have servlet-generated HTML that has a table and one or two divs depending on configuration. Here's a quick sample:

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td.td-div {
    width: 80%;
}
td.td-text {
    background-color: #faf0ff;
    width: 20%;
}
div#outer {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f0fffa;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.div-first, div.div-second {
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: .1em 0 .1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-div">
            <div id="outer">
                <div class="div-first">first div</div>
                <div class="div-second">Second div</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-text">It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, that I need that divs to fill the whole td, no matter if there is just one or both of them. Is it possible to spread first and second divs, (or just stretch the first div if there's no second) to the cell with only CSS?

**Update:** I need these divs ("first div", and "second div") to be 100% cell width, and 50% of the cell height when there are both of them, and  100% height when there is just one.

**Update:** The number of divs can be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution uses a combination of CSS `display:table` and `display:table-row`, it's also required to set **`height:100%` on the container `<table>`**.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6va4ts6a/)**

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.td-div {
    width: 80%;
}
.td-text {
    background: yellow;
    width: 20%;
}
#outer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.div-first, .div-second {
    display: table-row;
    background: aqua;
}
.div-second {
    background: teal;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-div">
            <div id="outer">
                <div class="div-first">first div</div>
                <div class="div-second">Second div</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-text">It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space.</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-div">
            <div id="outer">
                <div class="div-first">only div</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-text">It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:** The above solution doesn't seem to work properly on IE, here is the jQuery fallback for it.

```
$('table').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    $('#outer', this).css('height', h);
});
```

**[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6va4ts6a/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `flexbox` in your project you could probably do something like this:

CSS

```
td.td-div
{
    width: 80%;
    position:relative; /*added*/
}

div#outer
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f0fffa;
    display: flex; /*added*/
    flex-direction:column; /*added*/
    position:absolute; /*added*/
    top:0; /*added*/
}
div.div-first,
div.div-second
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: .1em 0 .1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; /*added*/
}
```

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8agt94dw/1/) for a demo. Remove the `div-second` and hit Run in the Fiddle and you'll see the first div will take up the whole td, or add a third div and see it fill up the whole space evenly.

**UPDATE**

To achieve something for older browsers (looking at you IE) you could use javascript, like this (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    var h =  $('table').height() / $('div#outer').children().length;
    $('div#outer > div').height(h);
});
```

Comment: Sadly, I have to support IE9. As I understand, flex is supported since ie10 or even 11.

Comment: Well thats a shame :( Its hard to get dynamic, flexible-responsive layouts in those old IE browsers. Might have to use javascript

Comment: Sure, I can even generate some inline css (with height 50 or 100%) with my servlet that produces this html, but I suppose that there must be more "elegant" css solutin )
Will try to put them in the table then. Maybe it will help...

Comment: @BbIKTOP I have included a javascript solution for older browsers if it helps

Comment: Thank you, it's obvious. Maybe there is a pure css solution though.

Comment: @BbIKTOP Maybe, but good luck finding it with that IE9 requirement lol

Comment: customer hardly require that /

btw, it's such a simple thing, just wonder, why is it so hard to implement...

Comment: @BbIKTOP I think it may seem simple to us, but its hard for CSS to figure out the remaining height of dynamic elements.  This is probably because to divvy out the remaining height it needs to know the heights of your divs WITH content in them, but they need to render out first and other styles applied before it can even know that the remaining height is. I think this is what `flexbox` is suppose to fix. Else you may be stuck with javascript

Comment: Although SO.com asks me to stop discussion, just a little remark - as it was mentioned tere, it greatly works with 50% height and display:absolute layout, that's why I suppose it's not a problem really.

Comment: I really like your ideas as well @zgood too bad that it requires to work on older IEs, you have my +1 too.

Comment: @Pangloss lol thank you... someday in the future we won't have to support these bad browsers.... someday

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
function spanHeight(selectors, parents) {
  var $parents, $selectors;

  $parents = $(parents);
  $selectors = $parents.find(selectors);

  $selectors.css({
    height: (100 / $selectors.length + '%')
  });
}

spanHeight('.inner', '#outer');
</script>
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.td-div {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.td-text {
  background: yellow;
  width: 20%;
}
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top;
  0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.div-first,
.div-second {
  background: aqua;
}
.div-second {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-div">
      <div id="outer">
        <div class="inner div-first">
          first div
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-text">
      It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty
      space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill
      this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space. It's just a text to fill this empty space.
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table
```

Comment: @BbIKTOP please test the code, it actually does work. I have two of the examples in the snippet.

Comment: Surely, I've tested it! In your example divs have height:50% - that's why first div does not fit whole cell when there's no second div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div#container {
    padding:20px;
    background:#F1F1F1
}
.content {
    width:150px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.text {
    font-family: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#555;
}
```

Also: http://jsfiddle.net/atk71stg/1/
In the fiddle you may need to pull the divider to the left to resize the window to make everything appear correctly.

This makes use of the 'flex' display style. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but it might be.

Here is some more information about the flex display style:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: But in your fiddle, those divs ain't filling 100% of the cell. Is it possible to stretch them to fill whole cell somehow?

Comment: I think that's an artifact of the fiddle. If you move the divider bar to give the render more space it should fix it. Though this approach uses the flex stuff which I think you mentioned in another comment as not being a viable solution.

Comment: It's so. Unfortunately, they use ie9